How to render ultra-low FPS video with ffmpeg?
I need a video from a static 4K picture. And I need it fast (500x). For that I asked ffmpeg for FPS=0.05 and it worked, so I got 100 hours of ultra-hd "video" in 5 Mb in no time. After that I tried to add some sound, but it ruined everything. All the players now just show black screen, except VirtualDub, which plays fine. With luck, rewinding somewhere close to the end sometimes makes players play. With fps=0.2  MPC will play after 5 seconds of blackness (after the second frame comes). Lower values lead to infinite black.
This works:
ffmpeg -loop 1 -r 0.001 -i picture.png -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -t 100:00:00 -pix_fmt yuv420p 1.mp4
This does not:
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -r 0.05 -i 4K-logo.jpg -i sound.mp3 -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a libopus -b:a 64k -c:v libx264 -preset faster Done.mp4
Do you have any idea, what kind of problem is that?
What I tried: different players, most of them fail, different codecs and containers, tuning interleaving params so audio starts first, -vsync 0,1,2. I even tried to concat 1 second of high-fps video with the low-fps rest, then mpc stops or pauses a bit between them. So nothing works. Audio breaks it. Ideas?

The 2nd command plays OK with macOS QuickTime Player and QuickLook with .mp4 encoded with ffmpeg and ffmpeg7 with .png, .jpg and .mp3 input.
